# How to apply Lottie animation in splash screen?

Tags: c#, animation, xamarin, splash-screen, lottie

I'm trying to use Lottie animation in my splash screen.

I created a new xaml page that contains my AnimationView:

```
<StackLayout>
    <forms:AnimationView 
        x:Name="SplashView" 
        Animation="hello.json"
        Loop="true"
        AutoPlay="true"
        IsEnabled="True"
        IsPlaying="True"
        IsVisible="True"
        VerticalOptions="Center" 
        HorizontalOptions="Center" />
</StackLayout>
```

When the app is launched the MainPage should be the one who contains the AnimationView. I added an event 'SplashView.OnFinish' so when the animation is finished the page is changed to my Home page using NavigationPage.PushAsync.

Here is  the code behind

```
public SplashScreen ()
{
    InitializeComponent ();
    NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

    SplashView.Play();
    SplashView.OnFinish += SplashView_OnFinish;
}

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    SplashView.Play();
}

private void SplashView_OnFinish(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
}
```

Everything works but I can't see the animation just a white page.

The Navigation.PushAsync works but the animation doesn't show.

I tried the method OnAppearing to Trigger the start of my animation but still doesn't work.

Comment: Just a question out of curiosity that,According to me the screen which appear before main page gets load is splash. You need animation on splash, but if you assign this as main page then whats appear before main page gets load?

Comment: Yeh, i already have a background image as a true splash screen, this one just apear after, just kind of an extra accessory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can simplify the code-behind, and `PushAsync` returns a `Task`, so you need to `await` it.

```
public partial class SplashPage : ContentPage
{
    public SplashPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
    }

    async void SplashView_OnFinish(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
    }
}
```

For the XAML, you do not want looping enabled as the OnFinish handler would never be called. You can supply the `OnFinish` handler, etc... The biggest issue is that just using `Center` for the vert/horz options provides no size to the view, use FillAndExpand to try to match the containing view.

```
<forms:AnimationView
    x:Name="SplashView"
    Animation="hello.json"
    Loop="false" 
    AutoPlay="true"
    OnFinish="SplashView_OnFinish"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

Comment: Thank you, it works and btw it turned out that the problem was from the hello.json file. i change it, then it worked. i have one more question please. can i make xaml page as my true splash screen ? i mean this one its just a trick i already have a background image as default splash-screen. but if i can make a personalized XAML page as splash-screen it would be great.

Comment: @dr1sshamra No you can not use a XAML page as a "true" splash screen, personally on android I only use `windowBackground` within a theme, as fast as it can be and still display something on app startup.

Comment: For thoses downvoting the answer: the question was about forms SplashScreen page and the answer was strictly about it. Though we all understand there MAY be another subject of creating a native splashscreen.